# Why does Release Management Visual Studio Online only show 4 actions?

Tags: azure-devops, release-management

After installing Release Management client and connecting to my Visual Studio Online account I only see 4 actions.

[image: Release Management actions]

Online I see that other people have a lot more actions in their toolbox: [image: Release Management with a lot of actions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is correct since in VSO you do pretty much everything in PowerShell using the **Deploy Using PS/DSC** action. I have a blog post series on Continuous Delivery with VSO [here](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-with-vso/) that might be of use in understanding how to get going.

Comment: I stumbled a few times on your blog. It contains very useful information. Thanks for providing it! Also thanks for confirming that there are only 4 actions. The real underlying question was how to pass Azure credentials to a deployment script. I wanted to accomplish it by creating a custom action. That seems not possible at the moment. Could you share your experience and knowledge on how to pass Azure credentials to a deployment script via Release Management: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590974/how-to-pass-azure-credentials-to-a-release-management-deployment-script

Comment: Alas I haven't covered that. I see someone has answered your question though so hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As Graham pointed out what you are seeing is correct. On VSO RM only supports the DSC/PowerShell (vNext) pipelines.  But the on premises product also supports the Agent based solution which is where you see all the additional actions and can add our own.

If you look at how the [Agent based actions are created](http://donovanbrown.com/post/2015/01/19/How-to-harvest-the-out-of-the-box-Agent-Based-tools-from-Release-Management) most are PowerShell and you can modify the PowerShell to work in a vNext pipeline.  [Here is an example of making a script work in both](http://donovanbrown.com/post/2015/03/21/how-to-set-the-build-quality-during-your-release-with-release-management).  That would require that the PowerShell be a part of your project so RM would be able to execute it during your release.  Not as nice a solution as the Agent based but the next version of RM will address both of your concerns. There will be a way to establish a secure connection with Azure and a way for you to add custom actions or “Tasks”.

Keep an eye on DonovanBrown.com or follow me @DonovanBrown, I have blog post ready that I can’t post until the new RM is released.  Before anyone asks I don’t have a date.