# How to pass Azure credentials to a Release Management deployment script on a secure manner?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, release-management, azure-cloud-services, ms-release-management

**What I want to accomplish:**
I want to deploy an Azure Cloud Service via Release Management. I managed to get this working by following the steps outlined [in this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/02/09/deploying-azure-cloud-service-using-release-management.aspx). In the post the Azure publishsettings file is added to the project and used in Release Management to deploy the Azure package to a Cloud Service. So far so good.

**What is the issue:**
The Azure publishsettings file will also contain information about the production environment. I don't want that information to be available to all the developers and therefor I would like to have a more secure alternative.

**What did I try:**
I created a custom action which takes 3 arguments: subscription id, subscription name and certificate key. This way the Azure information stays in Release Management and can be passed to a script. *[This didn't work because the action is not shown in the Release Template Toolbox.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572584/why-does-release-management-visual-studio-online-only-show-4-actions/30578601#30578601)*

**What is my question**:
What is the best way to pass Azure credentials to a deployment script via Release Management on a secure manner?

Answer (score 1):

We have a solution for [Build today](https://twitter.com/DonovanBrown/status/615477433903362048) that will work for RM in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Publish Settings file is an important one with which anybody can get access to certain activities. And once how ever the way you pass on the publish settings file, it can be misused (if tried).

So along with the publish settings file, you need to add a bit of process to the deployment like - 
Inactive or remove the management certificate which will in turn invalidate the given publish settings and anyone should request for a new set of publish settings file before they actually start any release procedures.

Even though it adds a rough edge to your smooth flow of deployment process, as it is a live or production system, it is always better to tight the process and make it idiot proof.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm aware of the issue and that's the reason for the question. Do you have any suggestions how to implement this in Release Management?